# CSS works if one parameters and doesn't work if them more then one

Tags: css, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

and if I'm typing http://mysite.com/login it's works great, but if for example http://mysite.com/user/new CSS losing :(

Also I use smarty with header.tpl where it is written that js, img and css included maybe this is problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're including your CSS relatively (e.g. `includes/style.css`) instead of absolutely (e.g. `/includes/style.css`). It's hard to help more without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I use smarty syntax $smarty->display('header.tpl'); $smarty->display($page.'.tpl'); $smarty->display('footer.tpl'); for build final page. In header.tpl I have <html><head><link .... "css/style.css"></head><body>

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
<html><head><link .... "css/style.css"></head><body>
```

It should be:

```
<html><head><link .... "/css/style.css"></head><body>
```

Comment: @user1493344, I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your comment. Could you perhaps explain it differently, or give more code that we can work with?